# Many to many relationship defaulting to "all"

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have to tables A and B. I also have an associative table A_B that stores the relationships between table A and B. In table A, there are records that I want to relate to all records in table B (even records that can be added in the future).

Let's say I have A1, A2, A3 and B1, B2 and B3.

I want A1 related to B1 and B3

A2 related to B1 and B2

A3 related to all Bs

Then the A_B table will look like:

```
A1, B1
A1, B3
A2, B1
A2, B2
A3, B1
A3, B2
A3, B3
```

If I add B4, I will need to add a new record in A_B table to relate it to A3. How can I define "A3 is related to all Bs" without requiring the A_B table? I was thinking in adding a flag in A (a boolean is_related_to_all) but I think it looks wrong (I may end up with hundreds of is_related_to_all = false)

Is there any way of doing this using relationships?

**EDIT**

To add a bit of more of context:

**Table A** stores partners and **Table B** stores websites. Some partners are related to specific websites and some partners are related to all websites (and some partners may be not related to any website).

Comment: If you want a row in table A which is related to ALL rows in table B then you will need a foreign key for this row in table to all rows in table B. If you provide more context on why you need this, people may be able to suggest a better approach.

Comment: You likely have not quite thought through the actual relationships (note the plural) between your business entities. I suggest you edit your Question to describe the details of your actual entities. Or, if not easily intelligible by us, devise an analogy which fits your facts. Either way we need more info to give a proper solution. And you can delete the MySQL tag as this is a general relational database design question. Lastly, this might better be posted in the sister site, http://dba.StackExchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the Boolean, it will no longer be a traditional many:many mapping table.  Probably `FOREIGN KEYs` will no longer work.

But you can certainly code for it -- however, you would need to have special code a la:

```
if flag is set, do ...
else            do ...
```

That may turn into a `UNION` of two `SELECTs`.  Or it may turn into something else.  (I can't predict without understanding the use of this mapping table.)

Meanwhile, those partners that are related to *no* website can probably be handled by *not* being in the table at all.  (This may need a 3rd if/then and/or `UNION`.)

Answer (score 0):

You could consider a trigger on table B:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER relate_all_b_to_a3
    AFTER INSERT ON B
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO (A_B)
    VALUES ('A3', NEW.B)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE B=B;
END;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this thought is too weird - dont mind it - but you could roll it up the other way around. You could hava a A_HASNOT_B (a more intelligent name would be better) table. This way, new records in B will always be assigned to all records from A. You would simply have to invert a UX based user selection before storing relations.

So in your scenario, there would be the following records:

```
A  | B
=======
A1 | B2
---+---
A2 | B3
```

Depending on your scenario/usecase, this could either be elegant or completely stupid. If you end up having only a few relations, this is a bad solution, in this case, i would go for reaanbs solution (trigger). If you think most records of type a will be assigned to type b it could do the job in a very simple way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different approach from those of the other solutions. Looking at the problem from a more abstract point of view, you have two "subclasses" of A: those related with one or more B (let's call them A_relatable) and those with are always related to all B (let's call them A_related).
So I will suggest to represent your situation with five relations:

```
A(attributes of A)
B(attributes of B)
A_relatable (only primary key of A as foreign key, also primary key)
A_related (only primary key of A as foreign key, also primary key)
A_B(foreign key of A_relatable, foreign key of B)
```

In this way all the constraints can be verified, and you can define a few stored procedure to simplify the management of the data.